# Is it possible to render an ejs template without reloading the page?

Tags: templates, express, socket.io, ejs

I am writing a game server, where players enter a game room, then get paired with another player. I would at this point like to display the board without reloading the page, so I do not have to reinitiate the socket.

in app.js file

```
socket.on('challangeExcepted', function(playerToMatch){
        if(socket.player.id == playerToMatch.id){ 
            ejs.render('board', {
                units: 19,
                length: 600
            });
        }
});
```

However I cannot seem to get this to work. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell to completely change the html requires the page to be reloaded. You can however **update** the dynamic parts of your template using `res.update('page_element', '/template.ejs', '{whatever: 'you want to update'});`

Here is the documentation 
http://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/Templates

I ended up just using backbone.js to solve my problem which allows for large changes to the html without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try pjax:

It is a technique that reloads only the html in a certain part of the page and changes the address with pushState.

https://npmjs.org/package/express-pjax

https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui